# How to open new tab on Firefox using command line (on Mac)?

Tags: macos, command-line, firefox, shell

How can I open new tab on Firefox using command line (on Mac)? 
I've tried `open -a "Firefox" --args "-new-tab" "http://about:newtab"`. 
This will not work; it just brings Firefox to the front.

And `open -a "Firefox" http://about:newtab` will open a new window on Firefox,
but can't open a new tab on current window.

Comment: You might also ask on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not exactly what you look for, but I manage to open a new tab using `open -a "Firefox" "http://any.url"`. However, it doesn't open the about:newtab as you'd like it to.